# In SwiftUI, elements go outside the device area whenever I Try to put a background image

Tags: swiftui

```
//import SwiftUI

//

//struct ContentView: View {

//    var body: some View {

//                VStack {

//                Text("The Quranic Suras")

//                    .font(.title)

//                    .padding(.bottom, -15.0)

//

//                Image("rundown")

//                    .resizable()

//                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

//

//                Text("Knowledge is a must for Muslims, and the chapters are the opening of the Revolution.")

//                    .font(.title)

//                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.528, green: 0.273, blue: 0.179))

//                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

//

//                Image("surahNew1")

//                    .resizable()

//                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

//

//                HStack {

//                    Spacer()

//                    ZStack {

//                        Image("btn")

//                            .resizable()

//                            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)

//                        Text("RANDOM")

//                            .font(.body)

//                            .fontWeight(.bold)

//                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

//                    }

//

//                    ZStack {

//                        Image("btn")

//                            .resizable()

//                            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)

//                        Text("SERIAL")

//                            .font(.body)

//                            .fontWeight(.bold)

//                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

//                    }

//                    Spacer()

//                }

//                

//            }

//

//    }

//}

//

//struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

//    static var previews: some View {

//        ContentView()

//    }

//}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, crated another VStack " VStack(spacing: 0) and end of the VStack

```
type " .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(
                Image("Background Image")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .opacity(0.2)
                )"
```

get helped from chatgpt